# Neo4j and Linkurious community edition

Tags: node.js, neo4j, linkurious

Can we connect linkurious.js community edition with Neo4j. I know there is a plug in sigma-parser-cypher. I am new to both Neo4j and linkurious, please bear with me. Can I run both linkrious js and Neo4j in the same machine. Do I need tomcat..?

Answer (score 0):

you can connect linkurious.js to a Neo4j server directly with the [parsers.cypher](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/develop/plugins/sigma.parsers.cypher) plugin. You can run both on the same machine, and Tomcat is not needed.